# is there a specific name for this?

Tags: geometry, terminology, recursion, fractals

I am doing a project in which I try to relate math and art. So I know this may not really be math-y, but I was wondering if there was a specific name for this kind of shape attached & also, would it be considered a fractal? I thought so because if it does go on forever (infinite recursion), it does have self-similarity, but I wanted to check. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Is the image posted just a couple steps in an implied infinite recursion? If so, would [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaobO.png) be a better approximation of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ Mark McClure, yes — that's a nice image! But I don't think the iteration matters for the name...

Comment: @Helena: It matters. Your image does **not** have self-similarity at all. The one Mark linked on the other hand **does** (to within limits of representation as pixels on the screen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure how widespread this name is, but I have found at least some occurrences of *crown square fractal*. ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=crown+square+fractal&tbm=bks), [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=crown+square+fractal&tbm=isch), [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=crown+square+fractal), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=crown+square+fractal))

Brief look at the hits in those searches suggests that this terminology appears mostly in connection with [fractal antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_antenna).

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure if it considered a fractal but the reference to self-similarity is appropriate. In particular, it can be considered an example of the [Droste effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect).